# How to make all sentence stay in the container?

Tags: html, css, json, wordpress

I am learning how to modify Wordpress site and spent a couple days to fix this so far.  In the picture, there is one sentence overflow out of container and it affects user's experience. Desktop view is ok(still needs improvement) but mobile view is more problematic. Please have a look. Any types of advices will be much appreciated.

https://my-tenders.com/property/pro-window/

[Screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ez02s.jpg)

I tried css code using open.ai but no luck yet.

Answer (score 0):

you have this style:

```
.block-content-wrap .detail-wrap li strong {
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

make it:

```
.block-content-wrap .detail-wrap li strong {
  white-space: wrap; /* if will not work, add !important */
}
```

white space nowrap prohibits character wrapping

Comment: Thank you very much. I also want to move the sentence to very bottom. Do you know where or how to do it?